# Micro Services and Version Control how to handle deployment

Tags: version-control, microservices

I am currently trying to figure out how to handle version control with microservices.

From what I have read the best strategy is to have a separate git repository for each microservice.

However when it comes to deployment having to upload multiple git repositories seems pretty complex.

Specifically I am scratching my head as how I would deploy an update where multiple microservices require changes that depend on each other, and how to roll back to the previous versions should there be an issue with a production deployment.

This seems like a headache that most developers who use micro services have had to deal with.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, especially if this could be done with an existing library rather than building something from scratch,

thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy answer or library that could solve the problem, however there are strategies that can help. I have outlined a few below

Backward compatibility of service - Whenever you are releasing make sure that your API (REST or otherwise) works with previous consumer, this could be done by proving default values for the newer attributes.

Versioning of API - When changes you are making are not small and breaking, introduce the new version of API so that older consumers can continue to work with previous version.

Canary Deployment - When you deploy a new version of micro-service route only a small percentage of calls to the new service and rest of previous version.Observe the behavior and rollback if required.

Blue Green deployment - Have two production environment, one blue which is proven working and other green which is staging containing the latest release. When the testing is done green environment and you have enough confidence, route all the calls to green.

References

[Micro-services versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/maintain-microservice-apis)

[Canary deployment](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CanaryRelease.html)

[Blue green deployment](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have had a look at the 3 solutions you mentioned and it seems to have helped evolve my question in the process. While I would definitely create a deployment strategy similar to what is proposed above, my concern is more for the management of the deployment rather than the deployment itself. If I have for example 30 microservices and a change I make requires a number of other services to change is there a good way to manage these dependencies?

Comment: From what I have read so far the only solution I have found is to pass the version number during the call between service, and having previous versions always available. And while this is good enough for my needs I am not a big fan of this approach I would prefer something where the dependencies were handled automatically rather than during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plugin I wrote using some references: https://github.com/simrankadept/serverless-ssm-version-tracker

NPM package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-ssm-version-tracker

The version format supported is YYYY.MM.DD.REVISION